# Surface tension (capillary action)

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

Why we assume that meniscus that is formed when a capillary tube is immersed in a liquid is spherical (neglecting mass of the meniscus)? What will be the shape of the meniscus when mass is not neglected?

Comment: I think it may have to do with bubbles being spherical, i.e. a spherical shape minimizes the energy of the surface.